# how to record published images from USB camera to mp4/avi format

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) package to publish live images from USB camera. I want to save the all images published on image_raw topics to mp4/avi video that is easily portable.

Environment Details:
ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297570/how-to-record-published-images-from-usb-camera-to-mp4/avi-format/) by [yahska](https://answers.ros.org/users/36497/yahska/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Checkout the [image_view/video_recorder](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.video_recorder) node.

---

Originally posted by [kev-the-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36226/kev-the-dev/) with karma: 81 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yahska](https://answers.ros.org/users/36497/yahska/) on 2018-07-18**:
Thanks. after exploring for a while, I figured it out!